# Open Excel file inside Visual Studio

Tags: excel, visual-studio, editor, ms-office

I need to open an Excel file for editing included in a Visual Basic project

I'm able to open it using Excel application. The file is opened in an external Excel instance.

Is there an extension that allows to open Excel files inside Visual Studio as other documents?

**Update**: I'm searching something similar to [Excel Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GrapeCity.gc-excelviewer) but I need an extension for Visual Studio (not Code) and I need an editor to modify the content of Excel files. I think that the extension has to do something similar to [How to Integrate Excel in a Windows Form Application using the WebBrowser](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15760/How-to-Integrate-Excel-in-a-Windows-Form-Applicati).

Comment: I believe not: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/977ea4ea-8a20-4189-9fd3-7c8cc11332ec/how-to-open-excel-2017-from-visual-studio-2017#134870f4-99e2-48f9-99b8-5a0de2fb2480

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to modify the Excel file as a csv file instead, depending on how complex you file is (if it contains formulas it will not work). I have tried using csv before and I did not notice much difference between csv and excel files when I was using it and csv could easily get data, but if you need formulas, you may have to compute them in your code before editing the file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just right click on the file and select `Open With > Visual Studio`. Or within Visual Studio go to the Menu Bar and select `File > Open` and seect the file. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello! Sorry but your suggestion is not what I'm searching for. If I open an Excel file using File > Open, a new instance of Excel starts opening the file.What I'm searching is an embedded editor inside a document tab in Visual Studio.

Comment: Ohh, I'm not sure if a plug-in that allows you to edit Excel files even exists for Visual Studio